# SPDY & Nginx upload issues

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, spdy

I have this setting: an Nginx server with php-fpm and the http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

When I try to  upload a file after about 10MB it fails. This happens when SPDY is activated. When SPDY is turned off upload works fine.

Is anyone aware of a workaround/fix for this issue?

Comment: Similar on Apache, The first upload fails for me, but the second works

Answer (score 1):

have you tried Customizing the below section of your config., file

> /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini:

```
; File uploads
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

Post which don't forget to the Restart PHP background processes:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your issue is really SPDY related. SPDY got two different timeouts.
1) For the Keepalive

```
spdy_keepalive_timeout 180s;
```

2) For expected Data

```
spdy_recv_timeout 30s;
```

Maybe the filesize is bigger than SPDY is expecting and you run into a timeout. You could try to raise the values.